# blueimp limitMultiFileUploadSize

Tags: jquery, blueimp

sorry for english, i use blueimp to upload file on my project , it all ok but i cannot limit the size of file , not one but the sum of them , in the documentation there is :

```
limitMultiFileUploadSize
The following option limits the number of files uploaded with one XHR request to keep the request size under or equal to the defined limit in bytes:

Type: integer
Default: undefined
Example: 1000000
Note: This option is ignored, if singleFileUploads is set to true.
```

in my project i try to insert :

```
<script>
ì$('#fileupload').fileupload({ 
  singleFileUploads: false,   
  limitMultiFileUploadSize: 1000000  //1Mb


})

</script>
```

But don't work

than i add a part of code to the  upload template  (code with comment //mycode)

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script>var sizetotal=0;</script> //my code

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        {% sizetotal=sizetotal+file.size;//my code

  if(sizetotal>1000000){
               alert('Puoi caricare al massimo un totale di un Mb i tuoi file superano questa dimensione')
           }; //mycode  %}
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload && sizetotal<1000000) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{%


 } %}
</script>
```

Now if the sum of sizefile are more than 1Mb an alert appear and the button is disable , ther's another problem now , how can i subtract the file size that i cancel ?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem with you and got the answer from the source code

There is a `maxFileSize: 999000` in
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/js/main.js

And this is my code

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'xxxx',        
    maxNumberOfFiles: 3, //Only can upload 3 files
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG)$/i, //Accept image
    maxFileSize: 4000000, //Each file should under 4000000 bytes
    singleFileUploads: false,
});
```